# How to modify the android 4.2 default theme?

Tags: android, themes

When an app does not set the theme itself, it will call the system default theme.

Now the android default theme is black background and white text. I want to set the default theme due to my wish.

Who knows where can set the default theme in android project?

Comment: You can do it in [Manifest file.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The android manifest.xml has the attribut `android:theme="resource or theme"`. This attribut sets it to holo dark or light or your own declared theme. To use your own layout you msut declare and build your own layout in the res/values folder.

Here's the documentation about it: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

Answer (score 0):

In menifest.xml file you can set default theme like

```
<application
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black"
/>
```